# How to find optimal value of a certain variable using neural networks?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

In a data science task I have some physical data from the instrument and need to predict continous time value. The data is divided into signal samples with some peaks occuring before that target time. In order to create new features I will have to use some statistical information about the signal - but not necessarily for the whole signal sample.

I was thinking about dividing the sample into chunks and use statistical data derived from these chunks as separate features.
I could divide the sample into say 1000 chunks. But it can be that such division doesn't make much sense. Maybe it would be better to get statistical info from the first 10% of the sample, then, say, last 20% and so on. Or at least use some other value for division based on the specific sample. Maybe for some samples dividing into 1000 chunks is good but for some others it should 500 or 2000 etc.

My idea was to use Neural Network to derive that division value (or maybe a few values, like the number of chunks and their sizes)

Does it makes sense at all and if yes, any ideas how to do that? It sounds like something like parameter optimisation using neural network but googling such thing didn't give me the required result. 
Maybe someone stumbled upon similar problem?